# How I can split my input value in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_Code {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please input dice value");
        String pattern;
        pattern = input.nextLine();
        String[] parts = pattern.split("[d][-]");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String part3 = parts[2];

        System.out.println(
            "The Pattern is : " + pattern + "\n" +
            "Number of dice : " + part1 + "\n" +
            "Number of dice surface : " + part1 + "\n" +
            "Card numbers is : " + part3);
```

I will input `(**2d6-4, 3d6-3**)` this type of value with the scanner. now I want to split for 2d6-4(number of dice are : 2, the number of dice surface are : 6, the card number is 4) how can I split?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and split to multiple tokens:

```
 final String input = "2d6-4";
 final String[] tokens = input.split("-|d");
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

the output will be an array as:

> **[2, 6, 4]**

Dice, surfaces, card....

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringTokenizer.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class TestString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String token="2d6-4,3d7-5";
        String[] splitStr=token.split(",");
        StringTokenizer parser=new StringTokenizer(splitStr[0], "d-");

        while(parser.hasMoreTokens()){
            Integer value=Integer.parseInt(parser.nextToken());
            System.out.println(" value ="+value);
        }
    }
}
```

output-

```
 value =2
 value =6
 value =4
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to develop a regular expression that will identify all the tokens that splits the data.

In your example, you're splitting the data from either a `d` or a `-`. So you can do something like this:

```
String[] tokens = "3d6-3".split("-|d");
```

And then the contents of tokens would look like:

> [2, 6, 4]